# ACF - Get the top level Category ID when in child category

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I created a customfield to show a category image on every category.

But i also want so that the category image is showing in the child categorys  asweel. like this:

Main category > Child Category 1

The code below works, but only for the toplevel category.

Anyone that can lead me in the right direction?

Thx.

```
<?php $category_id = 'category_' . get_queried_object_id(); ?>
<?php $field = get_field( 'kategoribild', $category_id ); ?>

<!-- Header -->
<header class="product-header" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $field; ?>');">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
  $category_id = get_queried_object_id();
  $category = get_category($category_id);
  if( $category->category_parent ) {
    $key = 'category_' . $category->category_parent;
  } else {
    $key = 'category_' . $category_id;
  }
    $field = get_field( 'kategoribild', $key ); 

?>

<!-- Header -->
<header class="product-header" style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url($field); ?>');">
```

It checks if there is a parent category and sets the ID.